# Why is a named pipe as slow as writing to a file?

Tags: fifo

I'm trying to understand how named pipes work so that I can streamline my one-way interprocess communication.  I expect some overhead due to copying data into a circular buffer, which I would have thought is stored in RAM, and so I expected the pipe to be much faster than writing to a file (because RAM is orders of magnitude faster than disk).

Instead, I found that the named pipe (or anonymous pipe) is about the same speed as a file.  This is on a 3 GHz desktop with an ordinary disk drive (not solid state), running Ubuntu Linux.  Here's a simplified test program in Python:

```
import sys
import time
import random

megabyte = "".join(random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") for x in range(1024**2))

while True:
    before = time.time()
    sys.stdout.write(megabyte)
    after = time.time()
    sys.stderr.write("{} microseconds\n".format(1e6 * (after - before)))
```

Piping straight to `/dev/null`:

```
python test.py > /dev/null
```

yields 2.1 microseconds (constant) for each megabyte.

Piping to a file:

```
python test.py > /tmp/testout.txt
```

jumps between 500 microseconds and 930 microseconds (the larger value gets more common as the file gets larger--- presumably, it's looking for disk space).

Then the named pipe:

```
mkfifo testpipe
cat testpipe > /dev/null &
python test.py > testpipe
```

yields 640 microseconds (constant) and an unnamed pipe:

```
python test.py | cat > /dev/null
```

also yields 650 microseconds (constant).

Can anyone explain why the pipe's speed is more like the file's speed than `/dev/null`'s speed?  Might I have a switch somewhere that says, "run pipes through a file-based buffer, rather than a RAM-based buffer," and can I change that switch?  Might it be a kernel option or a shell variable?

Another interpretation: suppose that the disk output jumps between 500 and 930 microseconds because the 500 is just piping and the 930 is actually writing.  Then the 500 ~ 640 for piping in both cases is equivalent.  However, under that interpretation, why is there only a factor of two between piping and actually writing to disk?  [Websites that talk about RAM disks](http://www.storagereview.com/introduction_ram_disks) say that RAM disks are 50-200 times faster than hard disks.

Comment: Writing to `/dev/null` is actually quite cheap, while writing anywhere else - be it a file, a FIFO, a pipe or whatever - is much more expensive as it needs "a lot" of handling effort.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're not seeing any performance benefit because you're not actually hitting disk when using a file - the data's on its way to the disk, but your execution thread doesn't need to wait for it to land there, so you're not actually *seeing* the speed penalty of hitting the disk.

If you want to wait for the disk operation to complete to see how much slower that gets, call a `sync()` (how to varies on your python version, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983272/does-python-have-sync)) - you'll be looking at tens of thousands of microseconds just for your disk to seek a couple times to get the file written out (assuming it doesn't have some kind of fast write cache like in a RAID controller).

Comment: When do we get to stop worrying about the seek time of our block devices? :)

Comment: @EEAA All SSDs, all the time.

Comment: You're right: with a `sync()` the disk-write time becomes 74,000 microseconds on average.  (The `flush()` I was doing in one variation of my test didn't do it.)  So then my interpretation that the 500 ~ 640 microseconds per megabyte really is the pipe overhead makes sense, thanks.